# Svn and local folder authentication

Tags: svn, svn-client

There is good way to get access to repository with: `http://username:password@repoUrl` 
If you want to get access to svn folder on disc which isn't created by you, you would get always security error from `svn.exe` .

If A user checked out the codes from repository server to local disk(`c:\RepoFolder\ProjectX`) and B user wants to log  into same computer and run `c:\>svn list -R c:\RepoFolder\ProjectX\trunk`, svn will generate an error like

```
-     
C:\>svn list -R c:\RepoFolder\ProjectX\trunk
svn: E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://RepoServerName/RepoFolder/ProjectX/trunk'
svn: E175013: Access to 'http://RepoServerName/RepoFolder/ProjectX/trunk' forbidden
-
```

Is there way to retrieve list of svn like `file:///username@domain:password@repoPath` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
C:\>svn list -R --username UserNamee --password Passworrrd c:\RepoFolder\ProjectX\trunk
```

Very simple but they hided the answer behind this argument:

```
C:\>svn list -help
```